# Is there an open provider implementation for oAuth 2.0 used by StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I notice that there is an *oAuth* endpoint for the stackexchange API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

The [*OpenID* implementation used by StackExchange is open sourced](https://code.google.com/p/stackid/) at https://code.google.com/p/stackid/

**Is there an open source implementation of the oAuth2 provider capabilities used by stackexchange API?**
If not, any information on what [(C#?) implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries/) the stackexchange network uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're not using a library for OAuth 2.0 in the API.

For one, OAuth 2.0 is a lot simpler than OAuth 1.0a and as such the benefits of pulling in a dependency to manage it are a lot smaller.  We also had to deal with our existing OpenID dependency in the login/auth process, which is a fairly unique situation to be in.

Given how tightly integrated our implementation is (and the unusual nature of OpenID, not to mention having a separate domain [stackexchange.com] managing the OAuth flow) I doubt we'll ever be in a position to open source it.

Comment: Thanks for the authorized answer and mentioning the simplicity of OAuth 2.0.  Just for the record, is the separate domain for OAuth flow stackexchange.co or stackauth.com?